# PHP replace string with wildcards

Tags: php, regex, str-replace

I have a string that contains multiple substrings like `onclick="pcm_popup_open(2, 'Something')"` which I want to remove. The parameters in the function in the string will be different each time, always an `int` and a `string` though, so it could also be `onclick="pcm_popup_open(1, 'Something else')"`.

I don't really understand regular expressions well enough, and as far as I know I can't use a wildcard in str_replace. Could someone please help? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't completely get what you mean, but I can show you how to make the regex:

```
// step1: take the string, and escape it (hint: there's a function for this)
$regex = 'onclick="pcm_popup_open\(2, \'Something\'\)"';

// step2: replace the number, you can limit it with: {minLength,maxLength}
$regex = 'onclick="pcm_popup_open(([0-9]){1,}, \'Something\')"';

// step3: replace the string
$regex = 'onclick="pcm_popup_open(([0-9]){1,}, \'(a-zA-Z0-0]+)\')"';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this to replace your regex matches with nothing

```
$pattern = '/(\sonclick="pcm_popup_open(?:.*)")/U';

echo preg_replace($pattern, "", $test); // replace with nothing
```

Idea:

```
(                            # capture group open
    \s                       # match the space before "onclick"
    onclick="pcm_popup_open  # match that text
    (?:                      # open non-capture group
        .*                   # match anything
    )                        # close non-capture group
    "                        # match the closing onclick attribute
)                            # close capture group
```

Edit:

```
U                            # ungreedy modifier
```

Example: https://eval.in/108780

---

**Please note:** [It is not a good idea to use regex to parse HTML.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2812842)

Comment: On closer inspection: This seems to replace way more than it should, I think anything between the first and the last occurrence of the regex.

Comment: Put `U` after your pattern to make the match ungreedy: `'/(\sonclick="pcm_popup_open(?:.*)")/U'`

Comment: Or use `?` after the wildcard: `(?:.*?)`